# GL ES 2.0 Shader Debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, opengl-es, shader

Is there a way to debug Shader GL ES 2.0 for Android?
Launch the application on the Samsung S3 and crashes.
On the desktop, everything works.
Compiling Shader passes successfully. I.e. the problem is at the stage of working inside the fragment Shader.
I suspect some inconsistencies in the precision of the data.
I work in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I have been able to find for this question is: check out "Tracer for GLES".

The android developers blog introduced that tool with this post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/06/android-sdk-tools-revision-20.html

The screenshot shows the shader code and a list of shader objects... so I'm hoping this answers your question.

Comment: documentation for the tool: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html